# 70 pct char matching, query optimization

Tags: sql, t-sql, query-optimization, database-administration

we have created a search application font end as ASP.NET and backEnd as SQL server 2012.
Main tables in the search is T003 and T004 . and searching is 70% char matching. below is the query which takes 2 sec to 4 sec to return results.

```
SELECT T003CODE
    ,A.SUBLINEID    ,A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE  ,A.APP_REG_NAME ,A.APP_REG_NUMBER
    ,A.APP_REG_DATE ,A.FILING_DATE  ,C.PUBLICATIONDATE  ,A.COMPANYCODE
    ,A.CLIPPING ,b.ASSOCIATED_NUMBER    ,b.class    ,C.COUNTRYNAME
    ,A.TRANSLATION
FROM T003 AS A INNER JOIN T004 AS b ON A.SUBLINEID = B.SUBLINEID
    AND A.App_Reg_Number = B.App_Reg_Number
INNER JOIN T001 AS C ON C.SUBLINEID = A.SUBLINEID
WHERE (
        (
            PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 6
            )
        OR (
            PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 7
            )
        OR (
            PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 8
            )
        )
ORDER BY C.PUBLICATIONDATE DESC Offset 0 ROWS

FETCH NEXT 16 ROWS ONLY;
```

But we also need no of records matching the said criteria, which is taking around 40 sec. guys do see any scope or any bug in my query plz let me know.

total no of rec in this table is almost 2.5 cr. below is query for count..

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM T003 AS A
INNER JOIN T004 AS b ON A.SUBLINEID = B.SUBLINEID
    AND A.App_Reg_Number = B.App_Reg_Number
INNER JOIN T001 AS C ON C.SUBLINEID = A.SUBLINEID
WHERE (
        (
            PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 6
            )
        OR (
            PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 7
            )
        OR (
            PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 8
            )
        )
```

Comment: here the term being used for search is comfort.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to add **COUNT OVER OVER (PARTITION BY [PRIMARY KEY])** in your original query and take it in your app as a counter:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY T003CODE) as CNT, T003CODE
    ,A.SUBLINEID    ,A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE  ,A.APP_REG_NAME ,A.APP_REG_NUMBER
    ,A.APP_REG_DATE ,A.FILING_DATE  ,C.PUBLICATIONDATE  ,A.COMPANYCODE
    ,A.CLIPPING ,b.ASSOCIATED_NUMBER    ,b.class    ,C.COUNTRYNAME
    ,A.TRANSLATION
FROM T003 AS A 
INNER JOIN T004 AS b ON A.SUBLINEID = B.SUBLINEID
    AND A.App_Reg_Number = B.App_Reg_Number
INNER JOIN T001 AS C ON C.SUBLINEID = A.SUBLINEID
WHERE (
        ( PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 6 )
        OR ( PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 7 )
        OR ( PATINDEX('%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%[cfmort]%', A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST) > 0
            AND A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN = 8 )
        )
ORDER BY C.PUBLICATIONDATE DESC Offset 0 ROWS
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite the answer, but would this help performance-wise ? 
(More string-manipulation going on but Less `OR`-ing; you could put the 0.70 in a separate variable if you want for flexibility)

```
DECLARE @word varchar(8000) = 'cfmort'

SELECT T003CODE
    ,A.SUBLINEID    ,A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE  ,A.APP_REG_NAME ,A.APP_REG_NUMBER
    ,A.APP_REG_DATE ,A.FILING_DATE  ,C.PUBLICATIONDATE  ,A.COMPANYCODE
    ,A.CLIPPING ,b.ASSOCIATED_NUMBER    ,b.class    ,C.COUNTRYNAME
    ,A.TRANSLATION
FROM T003 AS A INNER JOIN T004 AS b ON A.SUBLINEID = B.SUBLINEID
    AND A.App_Reg_Number = B.App_Reg_Number
INNER JOIN T001 AS C ON C.SUBLINEID = A.SUBLINEID
WHERE A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_DIST LIKE '%' + Replicate('[' + @word + ']%', Convert(int, A.MARK_IN_GAZETTE_LEN * 0.70))
ORDER BY C.PUBLICATIONDATE DESC Offset 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 16 ROWS ONLY;
```